# Checking if collection contains field value?

Tags: apex, trigger

Here in my apex class I'm passing the account name same as company name but if condition logic doesn't exist and it moves to the else condition.

```
public class AdobeToLead {

    public static void adobeToLeads(List<Lead> leads){     
        Set<String> accNames = new Set<String>();

        List<Account> acclist =[SELECT id,Name from Account LIMIT 1];         
        for(Account a : acclist){
            accNames.add(a.Name);   
        }

        for(Lead l : leads){

          //This condition doesn't executed even i'm passing the same value(company)

          if(accNames.contains(l.Company)){

                List<Contact> clist = [Select ID From Contact Where Account.Name=:l.Company AND LastName=:l.LastName LIMIT 1];
                if(clist!=null){
                    for(Contact c1 : clist){
                        Webinar_Attendee__c  wa = new Webinar_Attendee__c();
                        wa.Contact__c = c1.id;
                        l.addError('Duplicate Found');
                    }                  
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Specifically, this condition doesn't executed even when I'm passing the same value(company):

```
if(accNames.contains(l.Company)){
```

Comment: *clist* is never going to be null. Do a *size()* check instead of a null check.

Comment: If you mean that the line with the if isn't being executed that would be because the for bucle  is iterating over an empty collection.

If you mean the line is executed but never returns true this is what I think: 
I don't see why AccName should contain the name of the lead you're just  doing a Query picking 1 Account without any WHERE clause so why should the names match? I think this is the reason you're not getting your condition satisfied.

Comment: How can you guarantee your SOQL on Account is retrieving data that is going to match an entry in your Lead list?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just arbitrarily select one `Account` record, which is going to fail virtually every time this method gets executed. The only way it would work is sheer dumb luck; even a broken clock is right twice a day.

What you're doing:

```
List<Account> someAccounts = [SELECT Name FROM Account LIMIT 1];
Set<String> names = new Set<String>();
for (Account someAccount : someAccounts)
{
    names.add(someAccount.Name);
}
```

What you *should* be doing:

```
Set<String> companies = new Set<String>();
for (Lead record : records)
{
    companies.add(record.Company);
}

// You will have to rename leads to records or vice versa
// I am not a fan of copy-paste programming 
// so I try to make it require a bit more thought

Map<String, Account> nameToAccount = new Map<String, Account>();
for (Account record : [SELECT Name FROM Account WHERE Name IN :companies])
{
    nameToAccount.put(record.Name, record);
}
```

Now you actually have the records you need, not just one arbitrarily. You can check if the record is in the map by its key:

```
for (Lead record : records)
{
    if (nameToAccount.containsKey(record.Company))
    {
        Account relatedAccount = nameToAccount.get(record.Company));
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Or just investigate the value:

```
for (Lead record : records)
{
    Account relatedAccount = nameToAccount.get(record.Company));
    if (relatedAccount != null)
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: Copy-paste mistake I guess `Map<String, Account> nameToAccount = new Map<String, nameToAccount>();`
should be `Map<String, Account> nameToAccount = new Map<String, Account>();` :D

Comment: Not copy-pasta, just before-coffee mistakes. Thanks for the catch.